# Why CSS is empty when SSL is on and appcache is enabled? (iPad, Safari)

Tags: css, ipad, ssl, mobile-safari, html5-appcache

I have created simple HTML page which uses HTML5's application cache feature.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="test.appcache">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>    
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <!-- App icon for iPad (3rd gen) with retina display -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="./img/app-icon/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
  <!-- App icon for iPhone with retina display -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="./img/app-icon/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
  <!-- App icon for iPad (1st and 2nd gen) -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="./img/app-icon/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
  <!-- App icon for iPhone (non-retina) and Android -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./img/app-icon/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <!-- Favicon for Android browser tabs/bookmarks -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./img/app-icon/favicon.png">  
  <link href="themes/theme1/splash.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />      
  <script src="js/src/vendor/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
</head>

<body>
  <h1>TEST PAGE</h1>
  <div id="splash">    
    <div id="splash-logo"></div>
    <ol class="loader"><li></li><li></li><li></li></ol>
    <img id="splash-gtechg2" src="img/logo.png"/>
  </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see it is pretty simple. Following is my manifest:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# Modified: Thu Jan 24 12:22:59 2013
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CACHE:
# js/src/vendor
  js/src/vendor/jquery.js

# img/app-icon
  img/app-icon/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png
  img/app-icon/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png
  img/app-icon/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png
  img/app-icon/apple-touch-icon.png
  img/app-icon/favicon.png
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
NETWORK:
  *
  http://*
  https://*
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
FALLBACK: 
  / offline.html
```

And CSS file is:

```
#splash {
  background-image    : url(img/background.jpg);
  background-position : top left;
}

#splash-logo {
  background-image    : url(img/splash-logo.png);
  background-position : center;
}
```

As you can see THEME css is not included in appcache cause in real application URL may change any time so it should always be served from network.

The problem is when I enable SSL on server CSS file is not loaded at all. It works fine if I use HTTP or if I put CSS and its images into manifest. 
Please note this is reproduced only on Mobile Safari. (I have iPad3 with iOS 6.1).

Steps to reproduce are following:

1. Open test page in Safari on iPad
2. Everything works fine
3. Close Safari entirely so it is not minimized but actually closed.
4. Open Safari.
5. Now it will try to restore last opened tab with our test page and here CSS fails to load.

So basically I even do not get "Mixed content warning" - it just silently fails to load.

At first I thought there is some problem with certificate but as soon as I remove manifest attribute everything works fine.

Trying to find solution for several days now but everything I try is not working so I decided to ask here. Any ideas how to solve this?

**Update 1:** This works fine on Chrome 23.0.1271.100 for iOS

**Update 2:** Reporting bug to Adobe and switching off appcache for now